# Can't find function theme package ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2, debian, package, themes

I am currently working on a Debian server (for my internship) and I'm using `ggplot2` to plot some graphics.

So, I load the package by writing : `require(ggplot2)` (tried too`library(ggplot2)`, same result). However the function `theme` is not recognized (which is a function from `ggplot2`).

To show you that the package has already been installed, here is an exemple of one of my graphic generated with `ggplot2` functions :

- The graphic : https://gyazo.com/83a6cac0829057da767a8a606491abfc
- The message from the server : https://gyazo.com/a48e7afa5615175a8e12b7326e2748b6

And here what I get when ploting a graphic with the function theme :

- Message from the server : https://gyazo.com/c171f2c3740dbea49736622d5a05c451
- The produced graphic on RStudio : https://gyazo.com/cf6e2dbee9a882087caad6c491084a32

The graphic can't be generated because he can't find the function theme. So I wanted to know if there are some tricks to load a function from a package, for example like that : `ggplot2.theme`

Or does it mean R is not properly installed on the server ? (we have followed the CRAN tutorial for Debian server : https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/ + for information we have installed the package with the console by writing : `apt-get install r-cran-ggplot2`).

```
require(ggplot2)

#Data
data_y <- c(14, 111, 4, 12, 80, 105, 120, 88, 108, 119)
data_x <- c("person1",
            "person2",
            "person3",
            "person4",
            "person5",
            "person6",
            "person7",
            "person8",
            "person9",
            "person10"
            )

#Dataframe
data_xy <- data.frame(data_x, data_y)

#Plot

p <- ggplot(data_xy, aes(data_x, data_y))
p + geom_bar (
        stat = "identity", 
        fill = "steelblue1", 
        colour = "grey", 
        size = 1
        ) + 

    theme (
        axis.text.x=element_text(
            angle=45,
            hjust=0.5,
            vjust=0.5
            )
        ) +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me (Windows, R 3.3.0). You can access function directly using double colons, e.g.: `ggplot2::theme()`. Note, that your settings using theme() is being overwritten by theme_bw(), reverse the order.

Comment: Yeah I have changed that (the copy pasted code is an old version). I'll try your double colons to see if it works.

Got this error after trying double colons : " Error: 'theme' is not an exported object from 'namespace:ggplot2' " :/

Comment: have you tried to remove the whitespace after theme? so like `.... + theme(...)`

Comment: can you post output of `sessionInfo()`? But, I'd nuke the R & pkgs install and reinstall.

Comment: Usually when you get an error stating that "x" is not an exported object from package "y" even though you KNOW "x" is somewhere in "y", you can try x:::y (triple colons). However: this is probably not the case here because I am quite confident that `theme` is exported from `ggplot2`. Furthermore, functions defined in a package and not exported are usually not to be used (except perhaps interactively) as it implies the developper will not take the utmost care to keep this function retro-compatible in future updates.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/5bb8f57cabaf5ea86b077a5f1d7c35e2

for the sessionInfo(), I find the R's version quite old ...

Comment: @loki yeah I have tried without whitespaces and the problem is still the same :/

Comment: R version is really old and there might be some problems with the ggplot2 package. I would update to the newest R version and evaluate new. Remember to include an up to date repository to your Debians "/etc/apt/sources.list" file. Default ones are often quite outdated for Linux systems. if you have no root access, install R in your /home directory from source and execute your R script from there.

Comment: Before version 1 (I think) ggplot2 used `opts` instead of `theme`. Perhaps this is the issue.

Comment: You should of course restart R after the installs.

Comment: @pat-s on this link : https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/, there is a way to have a decent version of R ? (I mean, the version 3.x at least)

Comment: For a backport of R 3.3.1 to jessie, simply add something like
`deb http://<favourite-cran-mirror>/bin/linux/debian jessie-cran3/`
to the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` on your computer. You need to substitute `<favourite-cran-mirror>` by one of the mirror URLs listed in the mirror list and `jessie` to the debian-version-name you use.

Comment: @pat-s That's how it works ... I know nothing about debian so thanks for the help, I'll try this.

Comment: @pat-s Thanks to you, it finally worked. Thanks a lot. :)